# Is posting identical multiple, but reasonable, answers a spam?

Tags: discussion

Just reviewed these three answers posted one after another:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/117940/86652
- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/117941/86652
- https://security.stackexchange.com/a/117942/86652

I wouldn't consider the first one (or even every single one on its own) a spam, but posting the same answer is somewhat on the verge of spamming, isn't it?

The answers reveal affiliation ("we"), describe features and the service itself is not commercial (hosted on github, at least several links deep I can't find any commercial).

On the other hand the questions were not marked as duplicate and that might be a source of the problem.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: We were discussing this on [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/for-http-meta-security-stackexchange-com-questions-2273-is-posting-identical-mu) a little while ago as well

Comment: What are you talking about? Either I am thick or what you re referring to has been deleted

Answer (score 3):

Having a quick follow-up:

I would have considered any one of those three potential spam. The three together: definite spam, and quite rightly nuked :-)

As @Tildal pointed out, two of those questions were basically asking for trouble anyway, and the third was an edge case.